# Firebase Dynamic Links with parameters

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a custom domain setup with Firebase Dynamic Links. The URL prefix is `https://example.com/link` and I am then able to create a new dynamic link that will resolve `https://example.com/link/article` to `https://example.com/article` within my app or on the website.

What I need to do is also pass the ID of the article that I want people to see. The copy writers need a URL structure that lets them cross-link articles, so it needs to be a URL like this: `https://example.com/link/article?id=123456` but when I test this in the browser it resolves to `https://example.com/article` .. this should be possible right? I shouldn't have to create a dynamic link for every single piece of content should I? Would I need to add `https://example.com/link/article/123456` so it links to that specific article?

If I were to create Dynamic Links using the REST API in a Cloud Function that is triggered when new content is added to the Firestore, would these links persist?

I know that using the long Dynamic Link format will give me what I need, as I can create the short URL with the param added. But this doesn't solve the issue of giving the Copy Writers a URL structure that is easy to use in their content. Maybe a Cloud Function that strips out the URL links from the body copy, and replaces it with the long-form Dynamic Link?